# how to concatenate mysql results in one string using php

Tags: php, mysql, web

This is code shows a specific teacher Time table, 
1--select teacher name from a drop down list and compare it from a table "assign_teacher", 2---where information of respective teacher is stored, 3---fetch class timing and student name and shows it.

```
    $query="SELECT * FROM assign_teacher WHERE teacher ='$nam' order by session asc " ;
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_affected_rows();

    if($row >=1){  
    while($ro= mysql_fetch_array($result))

    {  
    ?>

    <tbody>

    <td><?php echo $ro['session']; ?> </td>

    <td><?php $days=explode(',', $ro['days']); if (in_array("Monday", $days) ) {  
            echo $ro['student']; ?>  </td>
                            <?php }
            else echo "----" ; ?>
            <td> <?php if (in_array("Tuesday", $days)) {  
                    echo $ro['student']; ?>  </td>
            <?php } else echo "-----" ; ?>
    <td> <?php if (in_array("Wednesday", $days)) {  
    echo $ro['student']; ?>  </td>
    <?php } else echo "-----" ; ?>
    <td> <?php if (in_array("Thursday", $days)) {  
    echo $ro['student']; ?>  </td>
    <?php } else echo "-----" ; ?>
    <td> <?php if (in_array("Friday", $days)) {  
                echo $ro['student']; ?>  </td>
            <?php } else echo "-----" ; ?>
            <td> <?php if (in_array("Saturday", $days)) {  
                echo $ro['student']; ?>  </td>
            <?php } else echo "-----" ; ?>

        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
<?php } ?>
```

---

---

output is following table:

10:00-11:30am | John

10:00-11:30am | aleena

02:00-03:30pm | Ali

02:00-03:30pm | Smith

---

but actually I want this :

10:00-11:30am | John, aleena

02:00-03:30pm | Ali, Smith

---

I want names of students of same timing in one row  comma separated,
can someone help me to fix it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really need some data from your database to see how things relate.

However I assume you have a table of sessions for each teacher, with a column containing a comma separated list of days of the week of that session, and a column containing a student name for that session.

You then want output for each session, with a column for each day of the (working) week containing a comma separated list of students in that session on that day.

As such something like this:-

```
SELECT session,
        GROUP_CONCAT(IF(FIND_IN_SET('Monday', days), tab1.student, NULL)) as students_monday,
        GROUP_CONCAT(IF(FIND_IN_SET('Tuesday', days), tab1.student, NULL)) as students_tuesday,
        GROUP_CONCAT(IF(FIND_IN_SET('Wednesday', days), tab1.student, NULL)) as students_wednesday,
        GROUP_CONCAT(IF(FIND_IN_SET('Thursday', days), tab1.student, NULL)) as students_thursday,
        GROUP_CONCAT(IF(FIND_IN_SET('Friday', days), tab1.student, NULL)) as students_friday,
        GROUP_CONCAT(IF(FIND_IN_SET('Saturday', days), tab1.student, NULL)) as students_saturday
FROM assign_teacher AS tab1 
WHERE teacher ='$nam' 
GROUP BY tab1.session 
ORDER BY tab1.session asc
```

With some sample data I can check this works for your tables.

EDIT

Knocking up a test tables as follows the results of the above SQL are what I think you want:-

```
CREATE TABLE assign_teacher
(
    ID INT, 
    teacher VARCHAR(255), 
    student VARCHAR(255), 
    session VARCHAR(255), 
    days VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO assign_teacher(ID, teacher, student, session, days)
VALUES
(1, 'Azir', 'Shehzor', '10:00-10:30 am', 'Monday,Saturday'),
(2, 'Azir', 'Salar', '10:00-10:30 am', 'Monday,Saturday');
(3, 'Azir', 'Fred', '14:00-14:30 am', 'Tuesday,Wednesday'),
(4, 'Azir', 'Burt', '14:00-14:30 am', 'Tuesday,Wednesday');
(5, 'Azir', 'Sally', '14:00-14:30 am', 'Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday'),
(6, 'Azir', 'Sid', '16:00-16:30 am', 'Monday,Tuesday,Saturday');
(7, 'Azir', 'Bilbo', '16:00-16:30 am', 'Monday,Tuesday,Saturday'),
(8, 'Azir', 'Frodo', '16:00-16:30 am', 'Monday,Tuesday,Saturday');
(9, 'Azir', 'Maggie', '16:00-10:30 am', 'Monday,Tuesday,Saturday'),
(10, 'Azir', 'Lisa', '16:00-16:30 am', 'Monday,Tuesday,Saturday');
```

Results

```
session         students_monday         students_tuesday        students_wednesday      students_thursday       students_friday     students_saturday
10:00-10:30 am  Shehzor,Salar           NULL                    NULL                    NULL                    NULL                Shehzor,Salar
14:00-14:30 am  NULL                    Fred,Burt,Sally         Fred,Burt,Sally         Sally                   Sally               NULL
16:00-10:30 am  Maggie                  Maggie                  NULL                    NULL                    NULL                Maggie
16:00-16:30 am  Sid,Bilbo,Frodo,Lisa    Sid,Bilbo,Frodo,Lisa    NULL                    NULL                    NULL                Sid,Bilbo,Frodo,Lisa
```

EDIT

Putting that SQL in to your script:-

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT session,
                    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(FIND_IN_SET('Monday', days), tab1.student, NULL)) as students_monday,
                    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(FIND_IN_SET('Tuesday', days), tab1.student, NULL)) as students_tuesday,
                    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(FIND_IN_SET('Wednesday', days), tab1.student, NULL)) as students_wednesday,
                    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(FIND_IN_SET('Thursday', days), tab1.student, NULL)) as students_thursday,
                    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(FIND_IN_SET('Friday', days), tab1.student, NULL)) as students_friday,
                    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(FIND_IN_SET('Saturday', days), tab1.student, NULL)) as students_saturday
            FROM assign_teacher AS tab1 
            WHERE teacher ='".mysql_real_escape_string($nam)."' 
            GROUP BY tab1.session 
            ORDER BY tab1.session ASC";

$result = mysql_query($query);
while($ro = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{  
    ?>

    <tbody>

    <td><?php echo $ro['session']; ?> </td>

    <td>
    <?php 
        echo "<td>".(($ro['students_monday'] == '') ? "----" : $ro['students_monday'] )."</td>";
        echo "<td>".(($ro['students_tuesday'] == '') ? "----" : $ro['students_tuesday'] )."</td>";
        echo "<td>".(($ro['students_wednesday'] == '') ? "----" : $ro['students_wednesday'] )."</td>";
        echo "<td>".(($ro['students_thursday'] == '') ? "----" : $ro['students_thursday'] )."</td>";
        echo "<td>".(($ro['students_friday'] == '') ? "----" : $ro['students_friday'] )."</td>";
        echo "<td>".(($ro['students_saturday'] == '') ? "----" : $ro['students_saturday'] )."</td>";
    ?>
    </tbody>
<?php 
} 
?>
```

Note that your script is using the mysql_* type functions which are deprecated (ie, support for them is being removed from php). I have used those functions in my example as well for consistency with your current script but you probably should consider changing to the fully supported mysqli_* type functions

Comment: I've a table name "assign_teacher" , , it has column for "teacher" , "session" , "student" , "days" , and yes days are comma separated

Comment: 1 Azir Shehzor 10:00-10:30 am Monday,Saturday,

Comment: 2 Azir Salar 10:00-10:30 am Monday,Saturday,

Comment: this is some sample data from my database , ID , teacher , student , session , days *respectively

Comment: Edited with test data / table and the results from the query which I think matches what you want.

Comment: so how can I do this ?

Comment: I have added a sample script based on yours but using my sample SQL

Answer (score 0):

use mysql `GROUP_CONCAT` with `group by`

```
SELECT tab1.*,GROUP_CONCAT(tab1.student) as students FROM 
assign_teacher AS tab1 WHERE teacher ='$nam' 
group by tab1.timing order by tab1.session asc
```

Try this :-

```
$query="SELECT tab1.*,GROUP_CONCAT(tab1.student) as students FROM 
    assign_teacher AS tab1 WHERE teacher ='$nam' 
    group by tab1.session order by tab1.session asc" ;
```

Comment: can you please give me a solid code line ? so I can use it

Comment: use this :- SELECT tab1.*,GROUP_CONCAT(tab1.student) as students FROM assign_teacher AS tab1 WHERE teacher ='$nam' group by tab1.timing order by tab1.session asc@TehreemFatima

Comment: from where this "timing" variable come from ?

Comment: I replaced 'timing' with 'session' , now it is working , but it is not combining results

Comment: it is only showing one result , not even showing 2nd result with same timing in new row

Comment: I suspect it needs some way to group on the days column, but the days column appears to be a comma separated list of days. Can you post some sample data please?

Comment: <select multiple="multiple" name="days[]" class="chzn-select span4" placeholder="Select Days" required>
                                          
                                              <option>Monday</option><option>Tuesday</option><option>Wednesday</option><option>Thursday</option><option>Friday</option><option>Saturday</option><option>Sunday</option>
             </select>

Comment: this is how I am taking input for days

Comment: [1  Azir  Shehzor  10:00-10:30 am  Monday,Saturday,]
[2  Azir  Salar  10:00-10:30 am  Monday,Saturday,]

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
$query="SELECT a.*,GROUP_CONCAT(a.student SEPARATOR ',') as students FROM assign_teacher AS a WHERE teacher ='$nam' group by a.timing order by a.session asc " ;
```

Comment: from where this "timing" variable came ?

Comment: just consider as an example,replace timing with your field in the database.

Comment: yes I changed with 'session' , but not working , only showing one result , not the second with same timing